# After Nvidia update my GTX760 hdmi port stopped working

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

After an Nvidia Update my hdmi stopped sending signal AFTER the windows logo.

During the boot it's fine, using other OS (Linux, Mac os X) no problems at all: just windows stops working.

If I use the DVI to VGA it works fine but the quality is pure horror.

I know I should remove drivers and install older ones but since this is a triple booting machine I have strong fear of destroying it.

What should I do to fix it without killing my working installation?

Comment: Roll the changes back, using a System Restore?

Comment: I'd lose installed applications (many): this horrible thing happened many days ago

Comment: But you can re-install applications? You may need to bite the bullet and start :(

Comment: That is, of course, a perfectly sure and working solution. I've decided to post here so a great guru could tell me: "Hey, do not format use this and do that and be happy" :)

Comment: Installing the 419.x driver update on Windows 10 caused me to lose my HDMI port on an GTX 1070 as well.

Comment: Hi there, @SwisherSweet!

5 years have passed but I am still alive & kicking :)

If I remember well the next Nvidia update fixed the issue for me so I'd suggest being patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for the next Nvidia update and installing it fixed the issue for me